# How to use camera to take photo in Xamarin Forms dynamically update profile

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I am new to Xamarin. I want to create a Xamarin Forms application to take a picture and save it in the profile. But I don't know how to use the camera and save the image in the profile and gallery in Xamarin Forms. Can anyone help me to take an image and save the image using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: “Xamarin forms camera” returns 671,000 results in Google.  14,000 on this site alone.  Did you attempt any research on your own before posting?

Comment: @Jason, I'm trying to follow some articles, but I couldn't find the proper guideline to reach my final goal.

Comment: I find a link but I have some doubts. I can't find out where I used the permission code. This is link https://www.xamarinhelp.com/use-camera-take-photo-xamarin-forms/

Comment: When I Install Media Plugin for the Xamarin plugin then I got a readme file, This file wrote In Android, add these permissions. But which page/were used this code, I can't find out, Can you tell me where used it?

Comment: This is permission code  [assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]

Comment: if you are trying something and have a specific problem, please post a question about that problem, including the relevant details.  Please see [ask] for guidance.  Also note that link that you are following is 5 years old.  The answer I linked to is much more current.

Comment: I'm a very new stack overflow user. Thank you for your valuable advice.

Comment: [assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.flash", Required = false)]

can you tell me where to use this permission??